# Authenticating the call to webhook written in Azure function from App insights alert

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have configured Azure Application Insight for monitoring our systems and was trying to enable the alerting. I'm using app insight availability test which provides a functionality to call a webhook URL.

I wrote a webhook using HTTP triggered Azure function, but the problem is it exposes a public URL which if called will raise an alarm on our internal alerting system. So I plan to authenticate the call to webhook.

Is there any way I can authenticate the call possibly using OAUTH.I don't want to provide the token in URL, looking for something secure. Another problem with manually using token in URL is that token rotation will require manual work.

Any suggestions on I can automate this task which will take care of secret rotation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe token based authentication is the only possible route as of today as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-alerts-webhook#authenticate-the-webhook).

But I think you should still be able to use a Function App without worrying about key rotation since the function keys can be read through the Functions API if the `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType` app setting is set to `files` as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups#action-specific-information).